# how to limit filetype in upload to not to have php script to it

Tags: php

We have a free classified section in which a user can upload a image, how to limit user to show a error, if uploads a php file in it

We tried putting up a that if $StrFiles equals text/php, its not executing and still a php file is been uploaded. How to stop it. pl advise

```
        $FILE_PATH="uploads/classifieds/ads";
        $StrFiles="";
        $StrFiles2="";

        if((file_exists($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']))){
            if($_FILES['pic']['name']!="")
                {
                $dt = time()."s";
                if(!JFile::upload($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'],$FILE_PATH.JFile::makeSafe($dt."_".$_FILES['pic']['name']))){
                        return JError::raiseWarning( 500, "Unable To upload File".$_FILES['pic']['name']);
                    }else{
                        $StrFiles=JFile::makeSafe($dt."_".$_FILES['pic']['name']);
                    }
                }
        }
        if((file_exists($_FILES['pic2']['tmp_name']))){
            if($_FILES['pic2']['name']!=""){
                $dt = time()."s";
                if(!JFile::upload($_FILES['pic2']['tmp_name'],$FILE_PATH.JFile::makeSafe($dt."_".$_FILES['pic2']['name']))){
                        return JError::raiseWarning( 500, "Unable To upload File".$_FILES['pic2']['name']);
                    }else{
                        $StrFiles2=JFile::makeSafe($dt."_".$_FILES['pic2']['name']);
                    }
                }
        }

           if ($StrFiles =="text/php")
             {
            echo "No PHP files<br>";
             $ok=0;
              } 

            if ($StrFiles2 =="text/php")
              {
            echo "No PHP files<br>";
            $ok=0;
              }              


    if($StrFiles){
        $pic= $StrFiles;
    }
    if($StrFiles2){
        $pic2= $StrFiles2;
    }
```

Comment: An easy-ish way is - try to create an image from the uploaded image. If it fails, it wasn't a proper image.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Joomla, you could define a list of all allowed image extensions, and then use `JFile::getExt($filename)` to check if extension belongs to allowed ones.

for example

```
$allowed = array('jpg', 'png');
if(in_array(JFile::getExt($filename), $allowed) {
}
```

Comment: Probably not the best idea, as you could give any file an accepted image extension.

Comment: You could, but at least such code wouldn't be executed on the server